# Show Dialog Fragment when clicking tab using android support TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I want to show `DialogFragment` popup when clicking 5th tab in a support `TabLayout` and I don't want to replace fragment or tab position when clicking the 5th item. for achieving that I did the following.

```
TabViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(ProfileFragment.create(mProfileId), getString(R.string.profile));
adapter.addFragment(NewsFragment.create(getString(R.string.news_feed)), getString(R.string.news_feed));
adapter.addFragment(AlertFragment.create(mProfileId), getString(R.string.alert));
adapter.addFragment(EventsFragment.create(mProfileId), getString(R.string.events));
//Logic implemented to show an empty fragment
adapter.addFragment(new Fragment(), getString(R.string.more));
```

Adapter

```
public class TabViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

And for showing More dialog

```
((ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MoreDialogFragment newFragment = MoreDialogFragment.newInstance();
                newFragment.show(ft, "ReserveChooser");
            }
        });
```

And It's working fine until I had updating support libraries to latest. After updating Dialog is showing but at the same time tab item replacing/showing that empty fragment ie,the 5th tab getting selected which I don't want . Any comments guys ?

Answer (score 1):

I have done that but don't know is the right way to do that waiting for a confirmation from an experienced one

```
 ((ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(4).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    MoreDialogFragment newFragment = MoreDialogFragment.newInstance();
                    newFragment.show(ft, "ReserveChooser");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if(tab.getPosition() == 4){
                    //show dialog
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```